# Pandas axis shift for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in Pandas, insert of data below.

```
Country Congo   Egypt   Nigeria South Africa
Date                
2020-03-16  0   11         0    0
2020-03-17  0   126        0    0
2020-03-18  0   166        0    0
2020-03-19  0   197        0    116
2020-03-20  0   210        0    170
2020-03-21  0   222        0    285
2020-03-22  0   245       10    240
2020-03-23  90  300       20    590
```

I am trying to plot a graph where:

1. all the columns have a the same starting point, say at 50,
2. shift all the lines to the new origin
3. have labels for the respective lines on the line or at the end of the line.

Please note: I am new in coding, I am learning. I didn't attach my attempt bcos I have no idea how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Please, don't use images in your question.

Comment: Do not include images of your dataframe, include them as text and format as code. Also, please state your attempt.]

Comment: It'd also be better if you can add a sample of your expected output